# divide file into equal counts

Tags: linux, command, suse, split

I have one .txt file which has more than 1 million record inside. (rownum from 1 to 1 million) I need to divide this file into two 500k files in linux. (file1 = rownum from 1 to 500k and file2 = rownum from 500k to 1 million).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the program `split`.

```
split -l 500000 file prefix
```